# Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource on Android

Tags: java, android, firebird, jaybird

Connection to Firebird database:

When I try to connect my android app to Firebird database I got following errors.

My LogCat :

> FATAL EXCEPTION : main
>                                                                                              Process: com.example.hms.firebirdconnection, PID: 26717
>                                                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource
>                                                                                                   at
>   org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractDriver.createDataSource(AbstractDriver.java:138)
>                                                                                                   at
>   org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractDriver.connect(AbstractDriver.java:124)
>                                                                                                   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
>                                                                                                   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
>                                                                                                   at
>   com.example.hms.firebirdconnection.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

I am using jaybird-full-2.2.3 and add dependency as module dependency.

My code is:

```
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            try {



                Connection connection DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:firebirdsql://xxx.xxx.x.x:3050//C:/User/DBNAME", "username", "password");

                String sSql="selecta.TDID,a.DOCTORNAME,a.ROOMNAME,a.TOKEN from TOKEN_DISPLAY a  where a.EMPID=2";
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sSql);
                String dr = "";
                if (rs.next()) {
                    dr = rs.getString("DOCTORNAME");
                }
                System.out.println("drrrrrrrrrrr=" + dr);
                );
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            return;
        }


    });
```

Gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hms.firebirdconnection"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro' 
          }
      }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/jaybird-full-2.2.10.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource`. You do not have this particular class in your library. Please download the driver from `https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/releases/download/v2.2.10/Jaybird-2.2.10-JDK_1.8.zip` and see the result.

Comment: The normal Jaybird driver cannot be used on Android.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't added the jar file 
once you add the module dependency ,go to project view and copy the jar file in lib folder ,it will resolve the method calls then

Comment: I added jar to lib folder but I got errors like  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/firebirdsql/ds/AbstractPooledConnection.class

Comment: then try removing the module dependency go to module settings by right clicking on the project because its already present in lib folder there is conflict in accessing

Comment: Run "gradlew dependencies" which will allow you to see all the libraries. You can use the "exclude" directive to remove duplicate libraries.
https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies

Comment: I changed jaybird to Jaybird-2.2.10. It showing errors like these -Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.

Comment: @user6313452 That is because you are trying to use the Java 8 version of the driver. But you can't use the normal Jaybird at all on Android.

Comment: which is the correct driver to use..please suggest for me

Comment: make sure ur using java 8 to compile because the library dependency are compiled with java 8 android
 {  
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
} 
You need to update java to version 8 and also build tools version 24 no need to get that maven repository because it contains duplicates

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the normal Jaybird (for Java). Jaybird cannot be used on Android because it depends on some interfaces and classes that are not available on Android.

You need to use ["Android Firebird JDBC Driver port"](https://sourceforge.net/projects/androidjaybird/), which is a port of Jaybird specifically for Android. Unfortunately the maintainer of that project hasn't updated it since Jaybird 2.2.4.

Comment: thank you sir for your suggestion. That problem fixed but now I got these errors      java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError      and java.lang.NullPointerException:

Comment: I suggest you post a new question, although I'm not sure if I can be of help. I maintain the normal Jaybird version and know next to nothing about the peculiarities of the Android version, although I believe you can run into problems if you haven't included the assets into your project.